# Java JSON Object Request - How to receive the JZON parts I need (android studio)

Tags: java, json, api

due to the fact that I am a newbie, I am sorry in advance for making you angry ;-)
I am currently working on a project and today I reached a milestone. My API-Request works.
I am using this URL:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=turkey
My problem is , that for my app I only need the "Extract" part of this JSON (at the moment i receive everything). How can I go on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(yourline);
        String loudScreaming = jsonResult.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("pages").getJSONObject("11125639").getString("extract");
        System.out.println(loudScreaming);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
public String getExtract(String json) {
    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("pages");
        object = object.getJSONObject(object.names().get(0).toString());
        return object.getString("extract");
    } catch (Exception e) { return ""; }
}
```

in different wikis, `pages` object might have different page ids. But every JSON result has `query`, `pages`, and `extract`.

so we use the first item in `pages` object and return `extract` text from there.